# zsh: Find out VCS of current directory

Tags: version-control, zsh

I'd like to create a zsh widget to perform common tasks of a version control systems with a single button. E.g. pressing F1 should call "svn status", if the current directory is part of a Subversion checkout. If it is in a git repository, it should call "git status -s".

Now, creating the widget is no big deal. But how do I determine which VCS is in the current directory?

I know about `vcs_info` and I use a lot. But I couldn't find any way to retrieve the most basic information, it provides. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for comments. My solution now looks like this:

```
vcs-status() {
   setopt no_autopushd
   cmd=""
   cur_dir=`pwd`
   while [[ `pwd` != "/" ]]; do
      if [[ -d .svn ]]; then
         cmd="svn status^M"
         break
      elif [[ -d .git ]]; then
         cmd="git status -s^M"
         break
      fi
      cd ..
   done
   cd $cur_dir
   if [[ -n $cmd ]]; then
      zle -U $cmd
   fi
   setopt autopushd
}
zle -N vcs-status
bindkey "\eOP"  vcs-status
```

Suggestions to cool zsh'ish improvements are welcome :-)

I also implemented the suggestion of Thomas, using `svn info` and `git rev-parse`. But then I noticed a problem: If I have an SVN working copy checked out somewhere *inside* a GIT working copy (yes, this is necessary occationally), or vice versa, I would only find the first one I'm checking. With the solution above, I find the "inner-most", which is what I want. In fact, this is a problem that also has been annoying me about `vcs_info` for a while.

Answer (score 2):

What about testing the existence of the specific meta data directories?

```
 if test -d CVS; then
    # CVS
 elif test -d .hg; then
    # Mercurial
 elif test -d .git; then
    # Git
 elif test -d .svn; then
    # Subversion
 else
    # unknown
 fi
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if it's that simple. In git there's the .git directory only in the root folder, but not in any subdirectory (also in newer versions of SVN, I heard). I would have search through all parent directories. Of course, that's also not a big deal, but I was hoping `vcs_info` would provide a function or variable for that (which I couldn't find).

Comment: Ah well, I guess I'll just go with your solution (and the mentioned improvements). Thanks! (I'll accept your answer if nothing better comes up in the near future)

Comment: `svn info` works in the subdirectories (*it* searches up to find the `.svn` directory).  `git` is equally flexible.  If the script were modified to test for non-error output from the respective tools, it would do what OP asked.

Comment: @George If the meta data directory appears only in the project root you would call this recursively up the hierarchy for the '# unknown' case until you reach `/`, at which time you know there is no VCS or an unknown one.